How to Sort an array on descending order with minizinc
In minizinc there is an inbuild sort function to sort a 1d array which sorts the elements by their ascending order. How do I do the opposite? I could not find a function directly associated with it. Or given I can use the sort function can I traverse this from end to start?
array[TYPE] of int: input;

% gives ascending ordered array
array[TYPE] of int: sorted = sort(input); 

array[TYPE] of int: reverse_sorted = ???? 



minizinc is a constraint programming modelling language which comes with it's own IDE.  https://www.minizinc.org/

@Mev and quite a good one too. But I will have to retake the Coursera course as a refresher, everything fell out of my brain.

I think this should work
array[TYPE] of int: reverse_sorted = [sorted[TYPE[length(TYPE) - i + 1]] | i in index_set(TYPE)];

Hmm didn't quite work and was a compiler error, but you gave me an idea to use the indexes to calculate it.
array[TYPE] of int: reverse_sorted = [sorted[TYPE[length(TYPE) - i + 1]] | i in index_set(TYPE)];
such a long-winded code... but hey it works!

A sort() combined with reverse() achieves a descending sort:
array[1..5] of int: a = reverse(sort([7,29, 3, 1, 29]));

output [ show(a[i]) ++ " " | i in 1..5];

Your example:
%  compiles with MiniZinc 2.8.7
set of int: TYPE = 1..5;
array[TYPE] of int: input;

% gives ascending ordered array
array[TYPE] of int: sorted = sort(input); 

array[TYPE] of int: reverse_sorted = reverse(sorted); 

output [show(reverse_sorted[i]) ++ " " | i in TYPE];


https://docs.minizinc.dev/en/stable/lib-stdlib-builtins.html#reverse

Thanks, this does not work as I get a compilor error. Either it has something to do with the version of compilor or have to import any library?
MiniZinc: type error: array index must be TYPE', but is int'
Process finished with non-zero exit code 1.
